# Using one function to update an object value used by another function using jquery?

Tags: jquery, object, properties, key, iteration

I am writing a quiz app that references an object with values, everything is working well, even though this is beginner code.  Specifically, I want the first question to be replaced by the second question when the user clicks the "next question" button.  But while my nextQuestion() is increasing the variable in the object, it's not changing in the rest of the code.

```js
var quiz = { //the questions, you get the idea//
  correctCount: 0,
  currentQuestion: 0, //THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO UPDATE IN EACH ITERATION
  questions: [{
    question: "Question 1?",
    answers: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    correct: "A"
  }, {
    question: "Question 2?",
    answers: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    correct: "C"
  }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".question").hide();

  //jquery event delegation
  function generateQuestion() {
    $("div.question").prepend(quiz.questions[quiz.currentQuestion].question);
    var answerList = quiz.questions[quiz.currentQuestion].answers;
    console.log(answerList);
    for (var i = 0; i < answerList.length; i++) {
      $("ul").append("<li>" + answerList[i] + "</li>");
    }
    console.log(quiz.currentQuestion);
  }

  function questionCheck() {
    $(".question-space").on('click', 'li', function(e) { //
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).val());
      if ($(this).text() === quiz.questions[quiz.currentQuestion].correct) {
        alert("Yes! The correct answer was " + quiz.questions[quiz.currentQuestion].correct + "!");
        quiz.correctCount += 1;
        $(".numCorrect").text(quiz.correctCount);
      } else {
        alert("Sorry! The correct answer was " + quiz.questions[quiz.currentQuestion].correct + "!");
      }
    });
  }

  function nextQuestion() {
    $(".next-question").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      quiz.currentQuestion += 1;
      console.log(quiz.currentQuestion);
    });
  }


  //Event listeners
  $(".start-quiz").click((function() {
    $(".box").hide();
    $("div.question").show();
    generateQuestion();
    questionCheck();
    nextQuestion();
  }));

});
```

Comment: You're missing the `]` at the end of the `questions:` array, and the `}` at the end of the `quiz` object.

Comment: What is `quiz.questions[ * * quiz.currentQuestion * * ]` supposed to mean? You can't use `*` like that.

Comment: If that was supposed to be code highlighting, you can't do markup inside code blocks on SO.

Comment: I've updated the syntax, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Can you add the HTML to the snippet so we can try it out?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/43b0c634ccef271f5b4696a22b46a2f8

Comment: just put a gist in case you wanted to play with the HTML, sorry this was my first SO question so still learning the best way to post code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was able to solve it after realizing I wasn't rendering anything in the function:

```
function nextQuestion() {
  $(".next-question").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    quiz.currentQuestion += 1;
    console.log(quiz.currentQuestion);
    $("div.question").empty();
    generateQuestion();
    questionCheck();
  });
}
```

I needed to change some of my jquery in the generate question function because of the `empty()` method taking out ALL of the descendants, but this at least got the functionality working.